# Rails insert column with ID on import CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have the following on my Occupant model:

```
def self.import(file)
 CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol) do |row|
  Occupant.create! row.to_h
 end
end
```

In my OccupantController I have

```
def new
 @occupant = Occupant.new(training_event_id: occupant_params[:training_event_id])
 respond_with @occupant
end
def import
 occupant = Occupant.import(params[:file])
 respond_with @occupant
end
```

I added new method simply to show that Occupant belongs_to TrainingEvent and training_event_id is required. Now users will be importing a list of data that does NOT have the training_event_id present. How do I update/add a column of the current training_event_id to the CSV?

I've been messing around with the activerecord-import gem but the same issue is present in that I cannot figure out how to add in the current ID of the TrainingEvent to the method that's on the model.

EDIT:

The form for the import exists on the Admin > TrainingEvent > Show and has:

```
=form_tag import_admin_occupants_path, multipart: true do
 =hidden_field_tag :training_event_id, value: @occupant.training_event_id
 =file_field_tag :file
 =submit_tag 'Import'
```

I thought maybe I could insert the training_event_id here but I'm guessing it's not applying the actual id to the file.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to move the import logic to `training_event` model as you can leverage `belongs_to` association, hence the code is more readable.

**OccupantsController:**

```
def show
 @occupant = Occupant.new(training_event_id: occupant_params[:training_event_id])
 respond_with @occupant
end

def import
 @training_event = TrainingEvent.find_by(training_event_id: params[:training_event_id])
 @training_event.import(params[:file])
 respond_with @training_event.occupants 
end
```

**TrainingEvent:**

```
# instance method instead of class method
def import(file)
 CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol) do |row|
  self.occupants.create row.to_h
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I figured it out so hopefully this helps someone else. I ended up adding the activerecord-import gem and did some small tweaks. The form will actually pull the current training_event_id as a hidden filed so I pass that argument into the model/controller.

Only issue that remains at the moment is getting the route after import to work. But that's a different story.

**Occupant Model:**

```
def self.my_import(file, training_event)
 occupants = []
 CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol) do |row|
   row['training_event_id'] = training_event
   occupants << Occupant.new(row.to_h)
   occupants.save
 end
 Occupant.import occupants
end
```

**Occupant Controller:**

```
def import
 @occupant = Occupant.my_import(params[:file], params[:training_event_id])
 respond_with @occupant, location: admin_training_event_path(@occupant.training_event)
end
```

**Admin > TrainingEvent > Show**

```
=form_tag import_admin_occupants_path, multipart: true do
 =hidden_field_tag "training_event_id", @training_event.id
 =file_field_tag :file
 =submit_tag 'Import'
```